# get specific item from json array using node js

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I have a json file. when i run this i'm getting the result as shown in the image. i need to get all the edge-label values only using node js.

[image]

Here is my code:

```
var fs = require("fs");
console.log("\n *START* \n");
var content = fs.readFileSync("publicapis.json");
console.log("Output Content : \n"+ content);
var jsonContent = JSON.parse(content);
console.log("User Name:", jsonContent.name);
console.log("\n *EXIT* \n");
```

Comment: Add json in textual format. Avoid adding images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 var values = [];
 jsonContent.forEach(function(obj) {
     obj.forEach(function(o) {
         o['public-api-path'].forEach(function(i) {
             values.push(i['edge-label']);
         });
     });
  });
```

Try this, but keep in mind I can't test it appropriately. Next time it would be better if you post well-formatted json text instead of an image.